# Unlist a list without losing NULL's

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a character vector as input and returns inconsistent results. If there are no NA's in the input, it will return a named vector of "translated" values. If there are NA's in the input, it will return a list. The element of the list corresponding to NA will be NULL with the name NA.

Here is such a list recreated:

```
foo <- list(a=1, b=2, c=NULL)
names(foo) <- c("a", "b", NA)
```

What I would *want* to have is a vector with NA's in the missing values:

```
c(1, 2, NA)
```

However, a simple `unlist()` does not work – the NULL element disappear. I tried the following:

```
foo <- lapply(foo, function(x) if(is.null(x)) NA else x)
names(foo) <- NULL
unlist(foo)
```

This works. However, foo is quite large (tens of thousands of elements) and it appears that the above code is rather slow. Is there a better solution?

Comment: @rajah9: no, this other question does not answer mine.

Comment: I did not vote to close; I only edited your question title.

Comment: ah, sorry, right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be:

```
foo[sapply(foo, is.null)] <- NA
unlist(foo, use.names = FALSE)

[1]  1  2 NA
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is much better.

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` has length of 0, so we can use that :

```
foo[lengths(foo) == 0] <- NA
unlist(foo, use.names = FALSE)
#[1]  1  2 NA
```